# Binding C-style callback setting functions to D

Tags: c, callback, d, glfw

I am currently in the process of binding the GLFW3 Library (I'm not using Derelict for a variety of reasons). This is easy enough to do and poses no real issues, except the following:

```
extern (C) {
    alias void(*GLFWwindowposfun)(GLFWwindow*, int, int);
    alias void(*GLFWwindowsizefun)(GLFWwindow*, int, int);
    alias void(*GLFWwindowclosefun)(GLFWwindow*);
    alias void(*GLFWwindowrefreshfun)(GLFWwindow*);
    alias void(*GLFWwindowfocusfun)(GLFWwindow*, int);
    alias void(*GLFWwindowiconifyfun)(GLFWwindow*, int);
    alias void(*GLFWframebuffersizefun)(GLFWwindow*, int, int);
}
```

Here is how one of the original declarations (in GLFW/GLFW3.h) is defined:

```
typedef void (* GLFWwindowposfun)(GLFWwindow*,int,int);
```

This *works* well enough in the sense that it compiles, however, it does trigger the following warning:

```
Source/MageLib/GLFW3.di(9): Deprecation: C-style function pointer and pointer to array syntax is deprecated. Use 'function' to declare function pointers
Source/MageLib/GLFW3.di(10): Deprecation: C-style function pointer and pointer to array syntax is deprecated. Use 'function' to declare function pointers
Source/MageLib/GLFW3.di(11): Deprecation: C-style function pointer and pointer to array syntax is deprecated. Use 'function' to declare function pointers
Source/MageLib/GLFW3.di(12): Deprecation: C-style function pointer and pointer to array syntax is deprecated. Use 'function' to declare function pointers
Source/MageLib/GLFW3.di(13): Deprecation: C-style function pointer and pointer to array syntax is deprecated. Use 'function' to declare function pointers
Source/MageLib/GLFW3.di(14): Deprecation: C-style function pointer and pointer to array syntax is deprecated. Use 'function' to declare function pointers
Source/MageLib/GLFW3.di(15): Deprecation: C-style function pointer and pointer to array syntax is deprecated. Use 'function' to declare function pointers
```

A bit of Googling got me the following resource: http://dlang.org/function.html#closures

I am not sure how to apply this though, I've tried doing this, but that evidently isn't working:

```
alias void function(GLFWwindow*, int, int);
```

That gives the following error:

```
Source/MageLib/GLFW3.di(9): Error: no identifier for declarator extern (C) void function(GLFWwindow*, int, int)
```

How would I convert this properly, the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alias GLFWwindowposfun = void function(GLFWwindow*, int, int);

Comment: Ah! I figured it'd be something like that, I forgot that callbacks are first class citizens in D. Thanks.